# How can I make such interface in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf-controls

I have in mind. For example click on the icon opens a tab.
http://img233.imageshack.us/i/e905423cab3b5c38acabf1d.jpg/

Comment: Please edit your question. Clarify what you want and put some effort into it.

Comment: It's a tool bar with pictures on the buttons. you have to make the pictures yourself.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the WPF Ribbon control, see articles and examples here:
[Announcing: Microsoft Ribbon for WPF RTW](http://10rem.net/blog/2010/08/02/announcing-microsoft-ribbon-for-wpf-rtw)

**EDIT**: as others said you could also do it with a toolbar with large icons, up to you and depending on what you need exactly...

Comment: I don't believe Compaqster's picture is a ribbon control. It looks like a vanilla tool bar

Comment: Yes, I want a toolbar with large icons. And for each icons
there is tab